# Permutations with repetition leading to fraction answer

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have the following scenario where I need to find the number of unique 4 digit numbers using the following 6 digits:
4,4,4,4,6,6
According to my understanding this can be derived by the following calculation:
6P4 / 4! . 2!
However this give the following answer 7.5?
Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: @String Thanks for pointing out that I'd misread the question!

Comment: @timtfj: You're welcome!

Comment: @String I should clearly post only when properly awake. Which isn't very often.

Comment: Dividing by $4!$ assume you have all four $4$s in you number and dividing by $2!$ assumes you have all two $6$s.  As you only have $4$ numbers, this just isn't the correct model to use.

Answer (score 1):

This corresponds to counting the number of 4-letter words formed from AAAABB. We have three cases:

- AAAA which constitutes a single solution
- AAAB and permutations ${}_4 C_1=4$
- AABB and permutations ${}_4 C_2=6$

This gives us a total of $11$ words.

---

There is a problem with the model in the [link](https://www.ck12.org/probability/permutations-with-repetition/lesson/Permutations-with-Repetition-BSC-PST/) you gave:
$$
\frac{{}_n P_r}{a!b!\cdots}
$$
where $a,b,...$ are the number of repetitions of the different items.

The problem is that this model breaks down whenever the number of unchosen items $n-r$ is greater than $2$ while there is at least one repeated item in the list. The reason for this is that the figures in the denominator also count permutations of the $n-r$ items that where NOT chosen, but the numerator only counts permutations of the $r$ chosen items.

> This is why the figure:
>   $$
> \frac{{}_6 P_4}{4!2!}=7.5
> $$
>   that you gave is too low.
>
> - The numerator ${}_6 P_4$ counts $4444$ as $4!$ permutations.
> - Whereas the denominator counts $4444$ not choosing $66$ as $4!2!$ permutations.
> - So instead of contributing one arrangement, the case $4444$ contributes only $1/2$ arrangement.

Similarly, the numerator counts $4466$ as ${}_4 P_2 2!=4!$ permutations, but divides them by $4!2!$ counting only half an arrangement. The same can be said for each of the ${}_4 P_4/(2!2!)=6$ rearrangements of $4466$. So those $6$ cases are only counted as half as many, namely $3$.

---

Conclusion: The method given in the link is useless when the difference between $n$ and $r$ is greater than $1$.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies. So it looks like the generic formula found in books for permutation with repetition cannot be applied for all the cases.

Comment: Please check the below link where it’s been advised to divide by number of factorial of the repeated item.     ...                     https://www.ck12.org/probability/permutations-with-repetition/lesson/Permutations-with-Repetition-BSC-PST/

Comment: @Ponniah: Ah, I see the problem! Perhaps you could include that link in the OP, and I will try my best to address is in my answer.

Comment: @Ponniah: I just added a large section on the problem with the method given in the link. Feel free to ask for clarifications!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, it’s very clear now!!!

Comment: The link don’t mention anything about what you have explained above. It’s very clear now, much appreciated!!

Comment: @Ponniah: I am delighted to hear that! I think the link is actually misleading. They should have a disclaimer about the limitation of cases this applies to.

Comment: Yes, they should have. I will try to write them so this can be corrected! Thanks!